# Titanium - Cant build for Device (com.apple.syslog_relay error)

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, appcelerator

I just upgraded my Titanium Studio to the latest version 4.6.0 together with CLI and everything.

The problem now is that I get this message all the time when I try to build for the device:

```
[ERROR] :  An error occurred during build after 52s 967ms
[ERROR] :  Failed to start "com.apple.syslog_relay" service (0xe800007f)
[ERROR] :  Try reconnecting your device and try again.
```

I found a thread on google/Jira with some "restart and disconnect instructions" but it didnt help. I've tried to reconnect and restarted the mac multiple times without any progress.
(http://appcelerator166.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=18496129&last=1&item=1)

Also; When I build for distribution, and then try to run it through XCode, I get this error:

```
[WARN] Attempted to load TiUIScrollableViewProxy: Could not find class definition.
[ERROR] The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'org.app_ios.module'.
Reason:
Class not found: Ti.UI.ScrollableView
Stack trace:

0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183c42db0 <redacted> + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001832a7f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   app_ios                       0x00000001000e00c8 app_ios + 770248
3   app_ios                       0x000000010006ca90 app_ios + 297616
4   app_ios                       0x000000010006c75c app_ios + 296796
5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183b33944 <redacted> + 132
6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183b337b4 <redacted> + 172
7   app_ios                       0x000000010006c368 app_ios + 295784
8   app_ios                       0x0000000100219ba8 app_ios + 2055080
9   app_ios                       0x0000000100229e1c app_ios + 2121244
10  UIKit                               0x00000001890f7030 <redacted> + 692
11  UIKit                               0x00000001890f7198 <redacted> + 80
12  UIKit                               0x00000001890e6298 <redacted> + 2360
13  UIKit                               0x00000001890fbc64 <redacted> + 104
14  UIKit                               0x0000000188e8c8c4 <redacted> + 176
15  UIKit                               0x0000000188d9c1e4 <redacted> + 656
16  QuartzCore                          0x000000018672e994 <redacted> + 148
17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001867295d0 <redacted> + 292
18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000186729490 <redacted> + 32
19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000186728ac0 <redacted> + 252
20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000186728820 <redacted> + 500
21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000186721de4 <redacted> + 80
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183bf8728 <redacted> + 32
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183bf64cc <redacted> + 372

24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183bf68fc <redacted> + 928
25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183b20c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
26  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000185408088 GSEventRunModal + 180
27  UIKit                               0x0000000188e0a088 UIApplicationMain + 204
28  app_ios                       0x00000001000296e8 app_ios + 22248
29  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001836be8b8 <redacted> + 4

[DEBUG] Application booted in 522.935033 ms
2016-06-10 16:32:46.165 app_ios[480:86488] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'org.app_ios.module', reason: 'Class not found: Ti.UI.ScrollableView'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183c42db0 0x1832a7f80 0x1000e00c8 0x10006ca90 0x10006c75c 0x183b33944 0x183b337b4 0x10006c368 0x100219ba8 0x100229e1c 0x1890f7030 0x1890f7198 0x1890e6298 0x1890fbc64 0x188e8c8c4 0x188d9c1e4 0x18672e994 0x1867295d0 0x186729490 0x186728ac0 0x186728820 0x186721de4 0x183bf8728 0x183bf64cc 0x183bf68fc 0x183b20c50 0x185408088 0x188e0a088 0x1000296e8 0x1836be8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Anyone who might have the same issue and have solved it?

Answer (score 1):

have the same problem, I have reported it here

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17595

Comment: I just re-installed my macbook, installed latest xcode, titanium sdk 5.3.0, latest node and everything. Still same error;

    [ERROR] :  The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'org.app.module'.
[ERROR] :  Reason:
[ERROR] :  Class not found: Ti.UI.ScrollableView

Comment: It should be a problem with last node. Try to read  https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17595 or open a new jira ticket

Comment: are you sure about this? Have you solved it? I have tried multiple versions of Node. Do you have specific version in mind? About opening a Jura ticket; Sure, if this problem was reproducable which it's not on my friends computer.

Comment: For me, the problem was sdk 5.3.0, with last 5.2.x works fine on device. I have read that problem sholud be solved in next releases. I don't know which sdk version.

Comment: This is my error message (I downgraded the Titanium SDK to 5.2.3): http://pastebin.com/d70Y56iN It does get built on the device, so that's fine. But this error message about "Class not found: Ti.UI.ScrollableView" is causing me the most problem right now. It didnt help to reinstall the whole computer.. (What Im doing is that I add a scrollableView to the Listview. It works in the Simulator though)

Comment: I'm not able to help you, if your respect all minimum system requirements (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Node.js) I suggest you to open a jira ticket.